# How do you keep Notepad++ from opening unsaved documents from the last session?

Tags: notepad++, autosave

Sometime around May 2014 Notepad++ had an update where it started saving unsaved documents without being told to.  When closing Notepad++ it no longer asks whether or not you want to save or discard unsaved documents and instead just closes.  When Notepad++ is opened back up the unsaved documents are there still, as before, listed as New 1; New 2; New 3; etc.  It looks like it is automatically saving them somewhere when it gets closed.

How do you turn this off, so that unsaved documents must either be discarded or saved when you close Notepad++?  How do you restore the old behaviour?

Comment: see this answer for an alternate solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656899/is-there-an-autosave-function-plugin-for-notepad

Comment: I had the opposite problem! Lost work when the new functionality caused me to just kill it from TM when normal UX was blocking the old workflow.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

With the Version 6.6 line of Notepad++ there is a new feature called "Session snapshot & periodic backup" which periodically (by default every 7 seconds) autosaves all of your work.  It was designed to make sure that you didn't lose your work in case the power went out or your computer crashed or something along those lines.  It is this feature that is autosaving unsaved documents.

It's pretty easy to turn off, the option for it is right underneath of the regular "Remember current session for next launch" option.  The option you need to turn off is located in the "Backup" section of the settings and is titled "Enable session snapshot and periodic backup", see the screenshot below.

[image: change backup settings]

Comment: @zellfaze This appears to disable the autosave feature. Is there a way to avoid this?