# How do I clear the previously opened files list in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I accidentally opened a very, very large file (well not accidentally, but I didn't think it would crash Notepad++). Now whenever I try to open Notepad++, the program crashes, so I can't just turn off the setting. I also don't have admin privileges.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/540286/notepad-how-to-reset-all-the-setting-to-default-ones

Answer (score 114):

Delete
`C:\Users\<YourUsername>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\session.xml`
or shorter
`%AppData%\Notepad++\session.xml`

Comment: Strangely, I don't even have a file called "session.xml" in that folder. I even tried deleting the entire folder, to no avail. And yet, Notepad++ still crashes with "Exception On WM_CREATE: Unknown exception" which I assume is from opening a file that is too large as it consumes around 1 gb of memory first.

Comment: @Kytuzian Are you using an up-to-date Notepad++ version?

Comment: I have version 6.7.8.2

Comment: @Kytuzian Does Method 2 from http://www.joomlaboy.com/tutorials/computers/77-solutions-remove-last-file-from-notepad-startup work?

Comment: @Kytuzian Maybe reinstall? That seems pretty weird

Comment: I guess I'll have to, I tried to edit the config.xml file in the %appdata%\Notepad++\ folder, but that particular setting doesn't seem to work (while the rest do).

Answer (score 10):

You might be able to run Notepad++ with the `-nosession` command line flag which is [documented](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/) as "*Launch Notepad++ without previous session"* (An earlier version of the documentation had *"Use this parameter to launch Notepad++ without loading the previous session (the files opened in Notepad++ at the last time).*)."

The `session.xml` file, plus other configuration files, can be in various locations. See the "*Configuration Files Location*" section of [this page](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#configuration-files-location) for the locations. (Actually the file locations are discussed in several places on that page.)

See also this answer [Notepad ++ doesn't save document on exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447786/notepad-doesnt-save-document-on-exit/24448488#24448488) which is about controlling whether Notepad++ reloads all its previous tabs when it is restarted.

Answer (score 4):

Simply delete

```
C:\Users\<YourUsername>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\session.xml
```

and

```
C:\Users\<YourUsername>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml
```

After that, the Notepad++ history of previously opened files will be empty.

Since Notepad++ v8.4.7 for recent files history clearing use menu **File** > **Empty Recent Files List**

[image: Before clearing]

After clearing the **File** menu will be look like:

[image: After clearing]

Comment: deleted config.xml and session.xml doesn't exist.  deleting config.xml didn't fix

Comment: @TechSavvySam try new tip, please)

Answer (score 3):

Type the path in the windows file explorer as follows:

`C:\Users\USER NAME HERE\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup`

Clear everything in this folder and that's it!

Comment: no directory on my system named backup under Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ v7.4.2 (32bit) | 
This solution requires no extra effort before or after launching Notepad++.

```
 Settings/Preferences/Backup
 Uncheck "Remember current session for next launch"
 It's at top under [Session snapshot and periodic backup]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of your file and delete the one which you tried open in Notepad++. Your Notepad++ should resume to its normal state.
You can then copy the file to its original path from the backup you took.

For large files, use `EmEditor`

Answer (score -1):

Access the below file:

```
%AppData%\Notepad++\config.xml
```

Delete unwanted search cache marked as `<Find name = “ BAD SEARCH”>`

Comment: File doesn't exist on my system