# How to disable Notepad++ Auto-open previous files without opening Notepad++?

Tags: editor, notepad++, settings

How do I stop Notepad++ from loading all files from the past session?

I know how to do that settings in Notepad++, but the problem is that I once opened a very large file (>10GB) and made the Notepad++ hang up. Notepad++ has already marked that big file in the session and therefore hang up everytime I start the Notepad++. Is there a way I can stop it from loading the past session so it won't hang up every time?

P.S. I have received a report on possible duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447786/notepad-doesnt-save-document-on-exit). This is obviously a different case. At least in that question the notepad++ still starts up normally while in my case I cannot even change the settings normally because the notepad++ just hang while loading the stored version. The answer to this question also provide a good way to change the settings without starting Notepad++, which will be useful in fixing problems caused by settings when the Notepad++ cannot starts normally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad ++ doesn't save document on exit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447786/notepad-doesnt-save-document-on-exit)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can change that setting by modifying the config file.

go to **%appdata%\Notepad++**
and open **config.xml**

You should find the following line in there:

```
<GUIConfig name="RememberLastSession">yes</GUIConfig>
```

just change it to **no** and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that folder. Once within the folder, the alternative is to edit session.xml and remove the file that is making trouble.

Comment: You should open config.xml with something else than Notepad++! Else it will just reset the config when you close the program.

Comment: You can do the same in settings: Settings > Backup > Uncheck "Remember current session for next launch".

Answer (score 12):

Start from command line:

```
notepad++ -nosession
```

"Auto-open previous files" then should be disabled

Comment: Although I guess that should work, when using windows, it is not a common practice to have PATH set to the position of notepad++. One may need to navigate to the notepad++ file path before using this command line.

Comment: I already had the problem of having a very large file that prevents to open normally notepad ++

I created at home a .lnk with this parameter to open notepad ++ cleanly

Answer (score 7):

If, like me, you left a huge file in the last session, you can also remove just the offending file from the session and keep the rest.

go to %appdata%\Notepad++ and open session.xml

Scroll to the right to see the filename.  Be careful to keep the integrety of the XML by removing the entire "file" node.  It should be on a single line.

Comment: This is also mentioned in the comment of the best answer. I guess it would be more meaningful if you can give an example of editing the XML?

Answer (score 5):

This is for those who do not want to modify the XML config filess, and this will also work without having the Notepad++ in PATH.

As I do not have enough reputation to comment on other answers, I'll add on Jacques Hubart's comment, all credits should still be for him.

1. Open Windows Run (Windows + R)
2. Type in the full path to the Notepad++ EXE.
   This would normally be *C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe*
3. Add the *nosession* parameter
4. Run

Preview:

[image: Run Preview]

Answer (score -1):

There is also another way from GUI
In Settings/Preferences/Backup uncheck the "Remember current session for next launch"

Answer (score -1):

As suggested use notepad++ -nosession from run to open notepad++. Then go to preferences --> Backup --> Uncheck Remember current session before next launch
Close notepadd++ and open it normally without run. It worked for me.

Comment: Why are you copying other answers?

Comment: As suggested where?

Comment: This is basically just Jacques Houbart's answer in this page.

Answer (score -1):

another possibility is that the window is on an other screen not visible anymore due to starting it in a new multimonitor setup.

in that case, you have to bring the windows in the visible area by:

- select the window by Alt+Tab
- Alt+Space opens a small menu in the top left corner
- Arrow-Down and Enter selects ' Move'
- Arrows brings it back

Comment: I was using one monitor only all the time, and I already saw the Notepad++ program opening up. I can see that in task manager. The problem was It just hung there and I had to kill the program with task manager.